# Present participle clause as object of a preposition

Tags: participle-clauses

Can I use an -ing clause in this case?

*A and B complement each other well, A **having** an extensive knowledge in the biological side of the project while B **being** focused on the geographical aspects.*

I hope it is clear what I am trying to say. A and B are scientists, one is a biologist and another is a geographer, so their collaboration is beneficial for the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*While* doesn't license participle clauses with explicit subjects, so you can't sustain that particular parallelism. But you're not required to; here are a couple of possible rewrites:

> A and B complement each other well, A having an extensive knowledge of the biological side of the project while B focuses on the geographical aspects.
>
> A and B complement each other well: A has an extensive knowledge of the biological side of the project while B focuses on the geographical aspects.
>
> A and B complement each other well: A's extensive knowledge of the biological side of the project is paralleled by B's expertise in the geographical aspects.

Comment: Can I write 'and' instead of 'while' in the original sentence?

Comment: @Sinusx Yes; but I would cut *being* as superfluous: "and B focused..."